# Cannot receive OSC message between two computers

Tags: c#, osc

I am new to C# and I am writing an application in C# and I need to receive UDP packets through OSC from another code that written in C++. I was running both codes on the same computer and everything runs fine and I receive all packets, I was using code similar to the one in here https://bitbucket.org/pvarcholik/bespoke.osc/src/4ef8350e4f2fea241b20f28916c2b0d52806fd7e/Samples/CS/Receiver/Program.cs?at=master.

Now I have to run each code in different computer and I changed the following:

"oscServer = new OscServer(TransportType.Udp, IPAddress.Loopback, Port);"

To: oscServer = new OscServer(IPAddress.Parse("134.190.XXX.XXX"), Port);

but the code stopes right at " oscServer.Start();" and does not receive any packet.

Any idea?

Thanks
Mohammed

Comment: can you ping the other address?

Comment: Yes I can, the other computer receives the packets but the C# code does not..!! Some people said I can only use multicast IP addresses within OSC server that are 224.X.X.X to 239.X.X.X. and I used one and the code keeps running but does not receive any message since IP is not correct..

Comment: I think my problem is how can I specify a computer not a multicast IP address within OSC Server?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I just used the ip address of the computer that received the message instead of the ip address of the computer that send the message.